# Kotlin - Unexpected tokens (use ';' to separate expressions on the same line) with ternary operator in lambda function

Tags: kotlin

I got an error `Unexpected tokens` error on the lambda function when I try to run this [code](https://pl.kotl.in/OIDLid831):

```
fun main() {
    val oddOrEven = { number: Int -> (number % 2 == 0) ? "Even" : "Odd" }
    print(oddOrEven(2))
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no ternary operator in Kotlin. See the discussion [here](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/ternary-operator/2116).

`if` in Kotlin is an expression (so it can return a value) and you can do something like this:

```
fun main() {
  val oddOrEven = { number: Int -> if(number % 2 == 0) "Even" else "Odd" }
  println(oddOrEven(2))
}
```

There is a special operator:

```
val x = if (y == null) -1 else x
```

The above can be shortened to:

```
val x ?: -1
```

This is called the Elvis Operator - if the value is `null` it returns the other value (-1 in this case)

Comment: (Effectively, `if…else` _is_ a ternary operator in Kotlin — it works exactly the same as Java's, just spelled differently.)